# conflict between R 3.1.2 and java7 config in ubuntu 14.10

Tags: java, r, ubuntu

(yes, I'll be searching the askUbuntu forums too).
Problem:  before upgrading, under Ubuntu14.04, I just installed the default JRE and JDK, and R 3.0.2 (the default for that rev of Ubuntu) sucessfully ran `R CMD javareconf`.

However, since upgrading to 14.10, and verifying I have the latest java7 JRE and JDK, trying to run the `javareconf` fails with the following dump:

```
cellocgw@cellocgw-Studio-1747:~$ sudo R CMD javareconf
Java interpreter : /usr/bin/java
Java version     : 1.7.0_65
Java home path   : /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre
Java compiler    : /usr/bin/javac
Java headers gen.: /usr/bin/javah
Java archive tool: /usr/bin/jar

trying to compile and link a JNI progam 
detected JNI cpp flags    : -I$(JAVA_HOME)/../include
detected JNI linker flags : -L$(JAVA_HOME)/lib/amd64/server -ljvm
gcc -std=gnu99 -I/usr/share/R/include -DNDEBUG -I/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/../include     -fpic  -g -O2 -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -Wformat -Werror=format-security -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -c conftest.c -o conftest.o
In file included from conftest.c:1:0:
/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/../include/jni.h:39:19: fatal error: stdio.h: No such file or directory
 #include <stdio.h>
                   ^
compilation terminated.
/usr/lib/R/etc/Makeconf:133: recipe for target 'conftest.o' failed
make: *** [conftest.o] Error 1
Unable to compile a JNI program


JAVA_HOME        : /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre
Java library path: 
JNI cpp flags    : 
JNI linker flags : 
Updating Java configuration in /usr/lib/R
Done.
```

Something is not installed or isn't where it "should" be.  I've tried most of the tricks listed at similar questions (doing updates and the like), but so far I haven't found a question where the `stdio.h` file missing was the error message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I've solved this situation:

Based on a comment from steeldriver at my [crossposting](https://askubuntu.com/questions/557351/cant-set-up-java-for-r-under-ubuntu-14-10), I dug into the Software Center and added several "add-ons" to the `gcc` installation.  I suspect that adding either `libc6-dev` or `gcc-multilib` was what I needed.

On a related note of probable interest to `R` users who want to install `JGR` : I had to install at least one of  `libpng12-dev`, `libpng3` , and `libpng++dev` to get the package `png` to install (in `R`), which is required for `JGR` to install.